# table sorting, paginating script problem

Tags: javascript, css

i'm trying to find table sorting and paginating script, and i've found a good one, but there is some problem i can't understand anyway.

look at [demo](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/table-sort-revisited/paginate/) please

the pagination must be in the center, but in IE it on the left side.
i've download the script and try to correct it, but i can't.

maybe you can understand what is the problem, or maybe can give the link on another such script, which works on all browsers.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jQuery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com)

Here's an example of the tablesorter with pagination plugin:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) is one of the most popular JavaScript frameworks around. You might want to consider this. :)